# Credhub implementation using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, pcf

Has anybody tried accessing the credhub referenced credentials through VCAP_SERVICES using Nodejs code? I am not sure if cfenv would help? `Parse.JSON` also does not seem to work (as the credentials are not returned in key value form in the credhub)
Something like this?

```
authName = vcapServices.credhub[i].credentials.adminUsername;
```

Comment: I got the solution for it. credentials node need not have to be used nor any extra libraries to be included. This will fetch the required fields.   authName = vcapServices.credhub.adminUsername;

Comment: Normally, you do not need to talk to CredHub. Just before your application starts, the platform will substitute CredHub placeholders in VCAP_SERVICES with the actual values from CredHub. Thus your app should just keep doing what it always does, and pull info from VCAP_SERVICES. Are you seeing something to the contrary? (note if you `cf ssh` in you will just see place holders)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes it did work for the spring boot applications without any changes. But in some Node js and Python apps, we were referring the credentials manually through a static path (inside "user-provided" service instance) for ex: authName = vcapServices['user-provided'][i].credentials.adminUsername; Where as credhub is a credhub service broker type instance.  Similarly for Python apps -  request = pcf_connection.request('/v2/user_provided_service_instances').

Comment: For what it's worth, the platform should interpolate all of `VCAP_SERVICES` so you really shouldn't need to do that, it is calling the interpolate API call on your behalf -> https://credhub-api.cfapps.io/version/2.5/#_interpolation_endpoint. You can certainly reach out to CredHub on your own, which it sounds like you are doing, but for most cases there is no need to. My suggestion would be to see if you can just get what you need without talking directly to CredHub. Even with the CredHub service broker you shouldn't need to do that. If you feel you do need to, update your question and explain.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had to make changes in the existing code so was looking for this option.